# Splitting, sorting and joining in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

Say I have an RDF graph which represents comments in a forum:

```
PREFIX rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX forum:  <http://example.com/>
PREFIX comment:  <http://example.com/comment/>
PREFIX meta: <http://example.com/meta/>

comment:1 a            forum:comment ;
       meta:created    "1234" ;
       meta:text       "comment 1" ;
       meta:commenter  "John" .

comment:2 a            forum:comment ;
       meta:created    "1256" ;
       meta:text       "comment 2" ;
       meta:commenter  "James" .

comment:3 a            forum:comment ;
       meta:created    "1267" ;
       meta:text       "comment 3" .
       meta:commenter  "John" .

comment:4 a            forum:comment ;
       meta:created    "1289" ;
       meta:text       "comment 4" ;
       meta:commenter  "James" .
```

Is it possible using a SPARQL query to pull out the latest comment of every `commenter`?

So we have to split up the data by commenter then within each sort by `created` then take the latest of each group and join them together. But I don't know how to do that in SPARQL.

Comment: if the values of `created` are always integer values, you should declare this in the RDF data, i.e. `meta:created    1267 ;` or the more verbose form `meta:created    "1267"^^xsd:integer ;`

Comment: `SELECT * {
  ?commenter ^meta:commenter [ meta:created ?created ; meta:text ?text ]
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?commenter ^meta:commenter [ meta:created ?created_ ]
    FILTER (xsd:integer(?created_) > xsd:integer(?created))
  }
}`

Comment: @Stanislav please make your comment into an answer so I can mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: This question was asked and answered many times. Perhaps "my" query is more universal, but @Karima's query may have better performance. So accept her answer please :-).

Answer (score 2):

Something like that probably ...

```
SELECT ?commenter ?text
WHERE {

   ?comment a            forum:comment ;
       meta:created   ?createdId ;
       meta:text      ?text .

  {
   SELECT (xsd:string(max(?id)) as ?createdId) ?commenter
   WHERE {
     ?comment a            forum:comment ;
       meta:created    ?created ;
       meta:commenter  ?commenter .
     BIND(xsd:integer(?created) as ?id)
   }
   GROUP BY ?commenter
 }
}
```

If I were you, I would rewrite the ontology in function of queries you want to ask.

Comment: Thank you for your help! However Stanislav answer's above in the comments worked better for my use case.